# Linear regression relationships

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, regression

Velocity $= X$, distance to stop $= Y$

$\beta_0= -17.5791$, $\hat{\operatorname{se}}(\beta_0)=6.7584$

$\beta_1 = 3.9324$, $\hat{\operatorname{se}}\beta_1 = 0.41.55$

degrees of freedom $=48$

(a) is there a linear relationship?

(b) Test $H_0:\beta_0 = -15$ vs $H_1: \beta_0 \neq -15$ at $\alpha = 0.05$

My solution below.

My $T$ test value shows that $T=-2.5791$

p-value $= 2\cdot\mathrm{pt}(-2.5791, 48)= 0.01302575$

since my p-value $<\alpha$ I reject $H_0$

Now my confidence interval for $\beta_0 = [-31.1635, -3.9947]$ and I feel i should not reject $H_0$

Does this mean that the answer for (a) is the relationship is not linear? or am I doing something incorrectly.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for $\beta_0$ contains $-15$, then you would not reject that null hypothesis.  Your t-statistic should be a fraction whose numerator is the least-squares estimate of $\beta_0$ (which you say is $-17.5791$) minus $-15$, thus $-17.5791-(-15) = 02.5791$.  The *denominator* of the t-statistic should depend on the standard error.  It appears that you neglect that part.  One doesn't use the t-statistic unless there is a denominator that includes an *estimate* of a standard deviation.

Comment: I indeed forgot the denominator, I do have it in my notes as 6.7584 as stated above. Once I included the denominator I got a T value of -.381612 in which case the p-value is greater than alpha and I don't reject H null. I then conclude that there is a linear relationship. Thank you